# Use file system as interface for data set

Tags: java, filesystems

I'm trying to use the file system actions (open, copy, move, delete, create directory, ... ) to manipulate my dataset (a tree structure). I'd like somehow to provide a network drive that would be mapped on clients.

I've already tried Alfresco jlan, and implementing an FTP or SSH server, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to do it or existing libraries (NFS? FTP? CIFS? SFTP? something else?)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a virtual disk / folder.

Such things are platform-dependent. I can see several variants when searching for "FUSE Java api" for Linux, and on Windows you can use Java API of our Callback File System product.

Another option is to create an NFS or CIFS server, but I don't know details.

Finally you can create an SSH/SFTP server and use client-side software to map the remote SFTP server as a local disk (for windows our company offers free SFTP Net Drive application).

Comment: FUSE is a path I didn't explore. Looks promising... I'll keep you posted.